# Where is sales_model_service_quote_submit_before dispatched?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Where in the source does the event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` dispatch in Magento 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the method `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::submitQuote` where the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` is dispatched.

A text search through the code directory with the event name would have given you what is needed.

Comment: Thank you that is it. @nikin How did I miss that.